# Webservice - response to different server

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

Is it possible for a Java webservice to build and return a response to a different server?

For example, client (A) on domain (A) makes a POST request to a Java webservice (B) on domain (B) which returns a response to server (C) on domain (C).

Comment: Why would you want to do that? "return a response to server (C) on domain (C)"?

Comment: Hi Thank you for your quick response! I really do not know why someone would like to do that! I started working at this company a month ago and today I was asked if I could do this for a client of ours.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if my answer would be satysfying but:

1. JAXB is not about webservices. It's Java Architecture for XML Binding. It is used to bind xml to object and the other way.
   What is important it is used by JAX-WS which is the reference implementation of Java Web Services.
   You can get more knowledge about those frameworks on [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) and [JAXWS](http://jax-ws.java.net/)
2. Webservices are common technology and and they are implemented in many languages., but if you want to know what they are capable of you could read documents on [W3C](http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/) which describe them. You could find that there are a few way of invoking webservices (and this is defined by particular service). Request-Response, One way etc. 
   As far as i know JAX-WS support only those i mentioned.

As Anugoonj said you probably want to do something like that:
A -> B -> C
where each arrow is one-way webservices operation.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into it. I know that the webservice uses JAXB and that it's a RESTful webservice... Anugoonj is almost correct. He is only wrong about the operation between B and C since server C is not running a web service that I know of.

Comment: If its RESTful webservice then there are no such operations I've described, cause there is no WSDL. If it had been BIG webservice then you might have thought about notification operation type. (still it's not implemented in JAX-WS). But I probably don't get the idea. It's hard for me to imagine situation like that: There are 3 person A, B, C. Person A ask B: "Where is Poland?". B responses to C "It's in central Europe". And C starts thinking what the hell B was talking about. So what C should do with answer from B for question he never heard of?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for asynchronous one way web-service methods.

Answer (score -1):

Of course.  You would need to code request recognition into your service logic.  I would try `(Http)ServletRequest.getRemoteHost`

However, doing it with an if statement will lead to code spaghettification.  I would build some sort of a hash map directory what to do with different IP (domains).

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply! I still do not know how this is possible with (Http)ServletRequest.getRemoteHost since getRemoteHost "returns the qualified name of the client or the last proxy that sent the request" but I need the webservice to return a response to a server that did not make the request.